# Creating a 'sort' method for array objects in a linked list

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, linked-list

I have a project that requires we create a an object array and then we place that in a linked list, I am kind of stuck because I have trouble writing/implementing my sort method that is supposed to sort the the linked list. Here is my code of how far I've gone. By the way, the object name is 'temperature'; Thank you.

```
public class SelectionSort
{
   private static void SelectionSort (Temperature[] array, int size)
   { 
      for ( int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++ )
      { 
         int indexLowest = i; 
         for ( int j = i + 1; j < size; j++ )
         {
            if ( array[j] < array[indexLowest] ) 
               indexLowest = j;

            if ( array[indexLowest] != array[i] )
            { 
               Temperature temp = array[indexLowest];
               array[indexLowest] = array[i]; 
               array[i] = temp; 
            }// if
         }//for j
      }// for i 
   }// method 
}
```

Comment: I believe Temperature is your own class. Can you post that and on what ground you wanna sort. Also check this - http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: "Have trouble" in which way? Explain what results you're getting and how they differ from the desired results.

Comment: This isn't C++. If it were, then have a look at [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Answer (score 1):

I think, your problem is the line

```
if ( array[j] < array[indexLowest] )
```

Both - `array[j]` and `array[indexLowest]` - are of type Temperature, according to your method's signature. So they are not primitive types and thus cannot be compared with `<`. This obviously results in a compiler error, that you really should have told us.

To compare objects like this, you have two possibilities:

1) Let the class `Temperature` implement `Comparable<Temperature>`. This interface will force you to add a method `public int compareTo(Temperatue other)` to your class `Temperature`. Implement this in the following way:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Temperatue other) {
     if (/* this is smaller than other */) {
        return -1;
    } else if (/* this is greater than other */) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

You could return any other positive or negative integer if you want to. Implement the comparisonyourself based on the fields in `Temperature`.

Use this in your problematic line as:

```
if ( array[j].compareTo(array[indexLowest]) < 0 )
```

2) Write a Comparator for your class Temperature.

```
public class TemperatureComparator implements Comparator<Temperature> {
    public int compare(Temperature t1, Temperature t2) {
        if (/* t1 is smaller than t2 */) {
            return -1;
        } else if (/* t1 is greater than t2 */) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The logic is similar. Now you can use this comparator in your sort method

```
private static void SelectionSort (Temperature[] array, int size) {
    Comparator<Temperature> comparator = new TemperatureComparator();
    ...
        if ( comparator.compare(array[j], array[indexLowest]) < 0 )
    ...
}
```